# ActiveX custom method not exposed

Tags: excel, activex

I have developed an application using visual studio 2017 and recently I have converted it to ActiveX (not sure if this is the right name, could be called "com application" but it is a dll).
It has graphic part and custom method part. Graphically it works in excel VBA, but I can NOT access the custom methods in the VBA code.

So far the dll has been digitally signed, and I have a com register and un-register methods as well. (I have registered it successfully using

`regasm /codebase /tlb myProgID.dll`

Question: What should I do to make the methods `LoadRecipeList` and `SetUpSqlConnection` work correctly in VBA? (I can see those methods in VBA object browser, but not the VBA intelliSense.
Also if I use following and it seems ok but not working with the custom methods.

```
dim myActiveX as object
set myActiveX = createObject("myProgID")
```

- [interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5hpc.png)
- [main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqk0O.png)
- [VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQbbq.png)

Comment: I have three pictures and somehow the title all stacked together. it should read as interface, main, VBA

Comment: Basically if someone can point to me how to develop an ActiveX using c#, that should solve my problem. So far internet examples are referring to c++ or VB (old version, not visual studio). Thanks a lot!